How best to get a value from an enum in TypeScript
I have an enum:
export enum Language {
  enUS = 1,
  zhHant = 2
};

I want a function that can efficiently get me the key based on the value passed:
export enum Language {
  enUS = 1,
  zhHant = 2
};

const languageMap = new Map<number, Language>(
  Object.entries(Language).map(([key, value]) => [parseInt(key), value as Language])
);

const mapLanguage = (languageCode = 1): Language | null => {
  return languageMap.get(languageCode) || null;
};

What is the most performant way because imagine this method is used against a million entries? Is it to use Map and Map.get()?

create a map and use map.get() like you said

I have tried:
`
export enum Language {
enUS = 1,
zhHant = 2
};
const languageMap = new Map<number, Language>(Object.entries(Language));
const mapLanguage = (languageCode = 1) => {
return languageMap.get(languageCode) || null;
};
`
However, what is confusing is that it loops 4 times, 2 times the number of enums for some odd reason

• Your mapLanguage function is pseudocode and syntactically invalid; please either [edit] to fix it, or delete it so we're not distracted by it. • A numeric enum already has reverse mappings so you can write LanguageEnum[1] to get "enUS", as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (or find a suitable duplicate target); if not, what am I missing?

Enums in typescript are tricky, but essentially they create a plain javascript object. When you have number values instead of for instance string values, the object will have both the keys and values as its keys, so you have both Language['enUS'] === 1 and Language[1] === 'enUS' and so on.

Nope, because the languageCode (values) are random, not ordered

If you do this instead: enum Language { enUS = '1', zhHant = '2' }, the values are strings, which leads to typescript not reverse mapping. It's stupid, but that's how it works

"Nope, because the languageCode (values) are random, not ordered" <-- who is this replying to?  If it's me, have you actually tried it? Reverse mappings still exist. You could write enum Foo {A=100} and then Foo[100] would be "A".  Please read the docs on reverse mappings and make sure you understand what it is before dismissing it.

Sorry, looks like the correct answer is Foo[100], thanks

So the function will just be
const mapLanguage = (languageCode = 1): Language | null => {   return Language[languageCode] || null; };

You don't need a function, just use an index. Why bother with null at all? I mean, feel free to do that, but it's not necessary to wrap a lookup with a function, is it?  Anyway, if you agree the reverse mapping meets your needs then I'll write an answer or find a suitable dupe target when I get a chance. If not, let me know soon, please. Thanks!

Numeric enums in TypeScript are automatically supplied with reverse mappings.  That is, the enum will also contain numeric keys that go to string values. All you have to do to get a key from the value is to index into the enum object with the value.  Observe that your Language enum compiles to something like this:
enum Language {
  enUS = 1,
  zhHant = 2
};

console.log(Language)
/* {
  "1": "enUS",
  "2": "zhHant",
  "enUS": 1,
  "zhHant": 2
}  */

So to get "enUS" from 1, all you need to do is write Language[1]:
console.log(Language[1]) // "enUS"

This means you really don't have to write a function to do this, since it's essentially just an indexing operation.
As for performance, it's not clear how best to measure that, so I'm not going to attempt to answer that. Depending on use cases, Map operations can be faster than the equivalent object operations. But the only way for you to know is to actually run some tests and then only think about changing the implementation if you hit a performance bottleneck.  If object lookups are too slow for your use case, you probably have a lot of other problems.
Playground link to code
